# illlegal static declaration in inner class Dog.DogTestDrive

Tags: java

illlegal static declaration in inner class Dog.DogTestDrive

```
    class Dog{

int size;
String breed;
String name;

void bark()
{
System.out.println("Wuff! Wuff!");
}

public class DogTestDrive{

public static void main(String []args)
{
Dog d = new Dog();
d.size = 12;
d.name = "pongy";
d.bark();
d.breed = "Labrodor";
}
} 
}
```

modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations

Comment: Why would you make DogTestDrive an inner class? If you make a normal class of it, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write instead `public class DogTestDrive` --> `public static class DogTestDrive`

```
class Dog {

    int size;
    String breed;
    String name;

    void bark()
    {
        System.out.println("Wuff! Wuff!");
    }

    public static class DogTestDrive {

        public static void main(String []args)
        {
            Dog d = new Dog();
            d.size = 12;
            d.name = "pongy";
            d.bark();
            d.breed = "Labrodor";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiles with no error,But after running the program Throws error "could not find or load main class DogTestDrive"

Comment: Have you copied the code 1:1? Because it is running when I test it